# How can I add multiple lines in the same dynamic diagram (Highchart)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

The problem I am encountering, is that I want to add 1 extra line (maybe more later) to this dynamic chart, but only one line is updating, that is to say I want to have two different lines updating with different random data on Y axis?

[This is the example I am working on, click here.](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/)

This is the code that I have wrote, if you want to see my problem then copy and paste this code in the link above.

```
$(function () {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global : {
            useUTC : false
        }
    });
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart : {
            events : {
                load : function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                count: 5,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '5M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 0
        },

        title : {
            text : 'Live random data'
        },

        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'diagram1',
            data : (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data1 = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

                for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data1.push([
                        time + i * 1000,
                        Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                    ]);
                }
                return data1;
            }())
        },
        {
            name : 'diagram2',
            data : (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data2 = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

                for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data2.push([
                        time + i * 1000,
                        Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                    ]);
                }
                return data2;
            }())
        }]
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your chart load event just add another interval for second series. 
To prevent code duplication you can store all your data in one object and iterate throu it.

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dpt83vm/).

```
$(function () {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global : {
            useUTC : false
        }
    });
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart : {
            events : {
                load : function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                    /* second series update code */
                    var series1 = this.series[1];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        series1.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                count: 5,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '5M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 0
        },

        title : {
            text : 'Live random data'
        },

        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'diagram1',
            data : (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data1 = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

                for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data1.push([
                        time + i * 1000,
                        Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                    ]);
                }
                return data1;
            }())
        },
        {
            name : 'diagram2',
            data : (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data2 = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

                for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data2.push([
                        time + i * 1000,
                        Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                    ]);
                }
                return data2;
            }())
        }]
    });

});
```

Comment: This does not work correct. If you scroll to left (Use the bottom scroll), you can see that the line is changing its body, strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach ;

```
 $(function () {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global : {
            useUTC : false
        }
    });

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart : {
            events : {
                load : function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series;
                    series.forEach(function(serie) {
                        setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        serie.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                    });

                }
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                count: 5,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '5M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 0
        },

        title : {
            text : 'Live random data'
        },

        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'diagram1',
            data : (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data1 = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

                for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data1.push([
                        time + i * 1000,
                        Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                    ]);
                }
                return data1;
            }())
        },
        {
            name : 'diagram2',
            data : (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data2 = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

                for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data2.push([
                        time + i * 500,
                        Math.round(Math.random() * 50)
                    ]);
                }
                return data2;
            }())
        }]
    });

});
```

Comment: This is an good idea, but what if I want to have different Y values? Let us say that I have two different sensors.

Comment: In your series you can define x,y and use in your diagram serie.x, serie.y etc. Or define a function which gives you x,y wtih diagram name. if name =  'diagram1' , x = 1 , y = 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, now I can have two dynamic lines. Is there a way I can add more dynamic charts without needing to dublicate setInterval etc, you can see the point below.

```
        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function () {
            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
        }, 1000);

        /* second series update code */
        var series1 = this.series[1];
        setInterval(function () {
            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
            series1.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
        }, 1000);

        /* third series update code */
        var series2 = this.series[2];
        setInterval(function () {
            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
            series2.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
        }, 1000);

        /* fourth series update code */
        var series3 = this.series[3];
        setInterval(function () {
            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
            series3.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
        }, 1000);
```